# different logos at iphone and itunes.?

Tags: iphone, graphical-logo

I had made app ..but the logo is different in itunes store and in the iphone..where is the problem..What should i do for both the logos to be same...

Answer (score 2):

Icons are different files. See section "[Creating Custom Icons and Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)" of "Creating Custom Icons and Images" apple documentation.

> Create a 512 x 512 pixel version of your application icon for display in the App Store. Although it’s important that this version be instantly recognizable as your application icon, **it can be subtly richer and more detailed**.